# Does the local window in VBA IDE have hidden elements?

Tags: excel, vba, ide

if I step-run `Set test = ActiveSheet` and look in the Local window I won't find a row with the name `OLEObjects`.
But if I step-run `Set test = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects` I get a list of `OLEObjects`.

I use the local window in vba very often to see how the tree structure looks. But this issue confuses me and I can't find out why when I have tried to searched for this issue. What am I not getting?

Comment: I suspect this is because [OLEObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.oleobjects) is a method which returns a collection of objects in the sheet. So you have to call the method to get the objects in the sheet

Comment: Thanks. How would you go about finding an unknown collection of objects?
For native VBA it's probably not a problem as it can always been found within the documentation, but what if there's poor or no documentation? Is there a way to find/search for such examples by code; i.e list them or print their names?

Comment: To understand that, it might be worth reading up on what is a **Method**, what is a **Property** and what are **Attributes**